# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter 28.0

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have a problem that has been going on for several days and I have not been able to solve it.

I need my application to connect to a database in Firebase and show it in a RecycleView.

I have the following:
Database in firebase:
[Imagen base de datos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7vpv.png)

I have the following dependencies:
[Imagen dependecias](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PWq5.png)

I created my model in the following way:
[Imagen modelo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKocx.png)

Create a Holder in the following way:
[Imagen Holder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oicVK.png)

After that, I have the following code so that according to what I find in the database I can publish the images of the links that are in this one.

[OnCreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41yXQ.png)

Create a sub that contains the entire connection

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN65B.png)

but in the part where FirebaseRecyclerAdapter is declared does not enter, this option is skipped and does not enter

```
private void loadMenu2() {


    FirebaseRecyclerOptions <wallpaperClass> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<wallpaperClass>()
                    .setQuery(category,wallpaperClass.class)
                    .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                    .build();

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<wallpaperClass, MenuViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull wallpaperClass model) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ingreso 3!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            holder.txtNombre.setText(model.getName());
            Picasso.get().load(model.getLinkwall()).into(holder.imgWallpaper);
        }


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ingreso 4!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

I've been with this for days, but I can not solve it, I thank everyone for their help.

Comment: please post your code add in side of question. please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not that the sentence is skipped, in fact it looks good the way you declared things, the problem is that the object "adapter" that you are creating does not assign it to any side ... you must pass it to your Recyclerview:

```
myRecycler.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

In this way your recyclerview, you know how it will have to be filled.

Regards!